# Primes as quotients

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

I ask this question based on a comment of David Speyer in [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/434766/1778). What primes are of the form
$$
\frac{p^2-1}{q^2-1}
$$
where $p$ and $q$ are prime?

The first prime not apparently of this form is 17. The Diophantine equation
$$
p^2-17q^2+16=0
$$
has solutions following a linear recurrence relation which has no primes in the first 1000 terms (only $(\pm1, 1)$ seeds may contain primes). But perhaps there is a better way to go about this?

Comment: You are looking for solutions $(p,q,r)$, all prime, to the equation $$p^{2}+r=1+rq^{2}.$$  I think it would be hard to show that there are even infinitely many such solutions, as the equation is nonlinear, and nonhomogenous.  To contrast, the significantly simpler $3$ variable equation $$p+q=2r,$$ which is translation invariant and linear, was only shown to have infinitely many prime solutions by Van Der Corput in 1939 using the circle method.  (This is equivalent to the statement "there are infinitely many $3$ term arithmetic progressions in the primes")

Comment: Let me point out that, for the linear recurrence, $(-1,1)$ is a distinct seed, the first positive pair is $(103,25).$ Then the new $(x,y)$ pair is $(33x+136y, 8x+33y).$

Comment: @WillJagy Why is $(1,\pm 1)$ the only relevant seed? Take $p=31$. The fundamental unit, if I am not mistaken, is $1520 + 273 \sqrt{31}$. I get that the seed $(61, \pm 11)$ is in the other orbit from $(1, \pm 1)$ and, sure enough $61$ and $11$ are primes.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer, just for ratio 17, which I worked out completely with Conway's topograph method. Your example is ratio 31. I just left a comment on your answer to the other question to the effect that ratio 13 exhibits four seeds.

Comment: @WillJagy: I actually checked (-1,1) to 1000 as well; let me edit that in. The only other seed has a common factor and so can't produce primes.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: $(\pm1,1)$ are the only relevant seeds for $p=17$; other primes have different seeds.

Comment: with the rate of growth of your linear recurrence, how did you checked if the 1000th term was prime?

Comment: @chubakueno: Most I could reject with trial division. For numbers without small prime factors I used a BPSW probable-prime test to prove compositeness.

Comment: Take a look at this paper: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?amp=&loc=refcit&refcit=171766&vfpref=html&r=3&mx-pid=1956141

Comment: If r < p ; p = A r + B where o <= r < B  (((r A + B)^2)-1)/( q^2 - 1) = r ; r(r (A^2) + 2 A B ) + ((B^2) -1 ) = r((q^2) - 1) ,therefore r|((B^2)-1) , r = (B-t) where 0 < t <=B. This implies (B-t)|(B t - 1) so (B-t)|((t^2) - 1); I don't know if this helps..

Comment: Also the order of B mod r would be 2 so r | (B + 1) yet B < r.

Comment: Like I mentioned if r < p ; p = (A r) + B, therefore r divides (B^2 - 1) so the order of B mod r is 2 ( r does not divide (B - 1)); (0 <= B < r). So r divides (B + 1) yet B < r. Contradiction, so This proves r >= p. DOES THIS HELP?

Answer (score 2):

I think for the equation:

$$\frac{x^2-1}{y^2-1}=k$$

It is necessary to record decisions. We will use the solutions of the Pell equation.

$$p^2-ks^2=1$$

And then the solutions are of the form:

$$x=-p^2+2kps-ks^2$$

$$y=p^2-2ps+ks^2$$